# Create a table with merged cell

Tags: tables

I would like to have a table to looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Is there a need for all the vertical rules, and the extraordinary horizontal rule party?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution that employs a `tabular*` environment. It also dispenses with all vertical lines and almost all horizontal lines. In some places where your template has full-width horizontal lines, I insert vertical whitespace as a visual divider. Remember that "negative space" can be every bit as powerful at providing a visual divider as horizontal and vertical lines are.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,multirow,ragged2e,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{8}{l} }
\toprule
Index      & Types    & Name     & Albedo    & 
Brightness & Particle & Emission & Rendering \\
\midrule
0 & ---                     &  Eeny \\
\addlinespace
1 & \multirow{4}{*}{Type 1} &  Meeny\\
2 &                         &  Miny\\
3 &                         &  Moe \\
4 &                         &  Catch\\
\addlinespace
5 & \multirow{4}{*}{Type 2} &  A \\
6 &                         &  Tiger\\
7 &                         &  By \\
8 &                         &  His\\
\addlinespace
9 & \multirow{6}{*}{Type 3} &  Toe \\
10&                         &  If He \\
11&                         &  Hollers \\
12&                         &  Let \\
13&                         &  Him \\
14&                         &  Go\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The package you are looking for is `multirow`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{0.092\textwidth}*7{|p{0.092\textwidth}}}
 \hline
 Index & Types & Names & Albedo & Brightness & Particle & Emission & Rendering\\
 \hline
 0 & & & & & & & \\
 \hline
 \hline
 1 &  \multirow{4}{*}{Type 1} & & & & & & \\ 
 \cline{1-1} \cline{3-8}
 2 &   & & & & & & \\ 
 \cline{1-1} \cline{3-8}
 3 &   & & & & & & \\ 
 \cline{1-1} \cline{3-8}
 4 &   & & & & & & \\ 
 \hline 
 \hline 
 5 &  \multirow{4}{*}{Type 2} & & & & & & \\ 
 \cline{1-1} \cline{3-8}
 6 &   & & & & & & \\ 
 \cline{1-1} \cline{3-8}
 7 &   & & & & & & \\ 
 \cline{1-1} \cline{3-8}
 8 &   & & & & & & \\ 
 \hline 
 \hline 
 9 &  \multirow{6}{*}{Type 3} & & & & & & \\ 
 \cline{1-1} \cline{3-8}
 10 &   & & & & & & \\ 
 \cline{1-1} \cline{3-8}
 11 &   & & & & & & \\ 
 \cline{1-1} \cline{3-8}
 12 &   & & & & & & \\ 
 \cline{1-1} \cline{3-8}
 13 &   & & & & & & \\ 
 \cline{1-1} \cline{3-8}
 14 &   & & & & & & \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that nowadays there is a trend towards having less dividing lines, and you could autonumber the rows. It may also be useful to use `tabularx` here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcounter{pft}
\newcolumntype{P}{%
       >{\stepcounter{pft}\number\value{pft}}%
       X
     }
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering\setcounter{pft}{-1}
\begin{tabularx}{0.95\textwidth}{P*7{X}}
 \toprule
 \multicolumn{1}{p{0.092\textwidth}}{Index} & Types & Names & Albedo & Brightness & Particle & Emission & Rendering\\
 \midrule
  & & & & & & & \\
 \midrule
  &  \multirow{4}{*}{Type 1} & & & & & & \\ 
  &   & & & & & & \\ 
  &   & & & & & & \\ 
  &   & & & & & & \\ 
 \midrule
  &  \multirow{4}{*}{Type 2} & & & & & & \\ 
  &   & & & & & & \\ 
  &   & & & & & & \\ 
  &   & & & & & & \\ 
 \midrule
  &  \multirow{6}{*}{Type 3} & & & & & & \\ 
  &   & & & & & & \\  
  &   & & & & & & \\ 
  &   & & & & & & \\ 
  &   & & & & & & \\  
  &   & & & & & & \\ 
 \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I dare to predict that in the not-too-distant future the trend will be to have less tables. In an age where data gets processed by computers we no longer need these enormous objects to show how the data looks like. (When was the time you had an actual phone book in your hands/claws? ;-)

Comment: +1. :-) Could you explain to the uninitiated how you chose `0.092\textwidth` as the common column width?

Comment: @Mico This was just a guess in the first version, which is only using `multirow`. The second version avoids this guess work by using `tabularx`. The rationale for posting two versions was not to overload the user with information when the only point is to mention the `multirow` package, and the second version is more advanced but designed in such a way that one can possibly appreciate what these additional packages do. (I am not claiming this is the way we should answer questions, but this was the rational for doing this.)

Comment: I was worried for a second when I saw the following title in YouTube: [Does Quantum Immortality Save Schrödinger's Cat?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTZZUjnrbF8) MY first thought was, "Oh no, why doesn't Schrödinger's cat stick to answering questions over on TeX.SE?!

Comment: @Mico I did not know that PBS started broadcasting quantum mystics. It is a bit sad, I generally like their documentaries on stuff that I do not understand. Having seen how they do on stuff that I understand (to some extent, of course) leaves me in an uncertain state w.r.t. how much I should trust their other statements. Well, maybe they *wanted* to get me in this state. ;-)